# Android Java/ getting Activity Context under onClick method

Tags: java, android, onclick

I am having a major problem developing an app for android as I can't seem to refer to my Activity context when implementing on click methods. The issue appeared after I did an update of Android Studio so I am wondering if it is linked to latest updates.

I have been trying to solve this through various ways of refering to the context but it seems to return a null context every time. The AlertBuilder Dialog works fine when not created under the onclick.

The app crashes at the line which implements onclick and I get the below error message on the debugger.

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated;

Regards.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo
>   android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object
>   reference

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public Charsequence Maintext
public Integer Referenceid
public String location

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Maintext = TextUtils.concat(textsave, Formulation.Formulate_Location(Referenceid, location), "\n");
}

public SpannableStringBuilder Clickable_Object() {
    SpannableStringBuilder Clickable_Object = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    ClickableSpan cscont = new ClickableSpan() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        }
    };
    return Clickable_Object;
}
}

public class Formulation {
public String Formulate_Location(Integer Referenceid, String location) {
    MainActivity Main = new MainActivity();
        textsave = Main.Clickable_Object();
        return textsave}
}
```

Comment: show more blocks will be easier to find out.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for answering I added an extended (summarised) code to show what i am trying to acheive. I want to call the clickable object from other classes (Formulation class) yet for the alertdialog to appear in the main activity when the text is clicked.

Comment: Firstly, you did not `setContentView` for Activity.  And then ,do not `new Activity` .